# Slow Response with Lumen

Tags: performance, lumen

I've been looking for hours for a solution, but I'm getting nowhere. Maybe somebody can help me or give me tips where to find the error.

I have a lumen backend with which I get the data from the database and send it to my Angular Frontend. My problem is that the response time is already very large, although I sometimes only fetch a few data.
Following example:

```
    $query = \DB::table('ip_netztyp')
     ->orderBy('netztyp')
     ->get();

    return $query;
```

This is my db query. It returns 16 values from the table like this:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "netztyp": "DMZ",
    "active": 1
},
{
    "id": 13,
    "netztyp": "LAN",
    "active": 1
},
...
```

But the response times are like this:

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMvyD.png)

[Chrome Network Tab Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZkJC.png)

[Clockwork Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfEMi.png)

So I don't think the db is to slow but why is the lumen response so slow?
I don't think that's normal.

How can I troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it with enabling opcache :)

https://www.hmazter.com/2019/04/speeding-up-php-docker-with-opcache/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)